# C linked-list remove function

Tags: c, linked-list, free

Here is my remove() function for a linked-list. How could it be better and why?

```
void removeData(void *data, struct accList *theList)
{
  if(theList->head == NULL)                  //nothing can be deleted
    return;
  else if(theList->head == theList->tail)          //there is only one element in the    list
  {
    free(theList->head);
    theList->head = theList->tail = NULL;
  }
  else if(data == theList->head->data)           //the node to be deleted is the head
  {
    struct accListNode *temp = theList->head;
    free(theList->head);
    theList->head = temp;
    theList->head->next = temp->next;
  }
  else if(data == theList->tail->data)      //the node to be deleted is the tail
  {
    struct accListNode *cur;
    for(cur = theList->head; cur->next->next != NULL; cur = cur->next);
    theList->tail = cur;
    free(cur->next);
    cur->next = NULL;
  }
  else                                     //the node to be deleted is any other node
  {
    struct accListNode *cur;
    for(cur = theList->head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {  
      if(cur->data == data)     //this is the node we must delete from theList
      {
        struct accListNode *temp = cur->next->next;
        free(cur->next);
        cur->next = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, could somebody give me a detailed explanation of the free() function. The words "releases memory pointed to by ptr" is not helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Questions of the form "how can I improve this code?" should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: [You're looking for Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of testing for all the different special cases, you could work with pointers to pointers of list elements and, since you're traversing the list anyway, keep track of the last element seen:

```
void removeData ( void *data , struct accList *theList ) {
    struct acclist *last = NULL, **finger = &theList->head;
    while ( *finger != NULL ) {
        if ( (*finger)->data == data )
            *finger = (*finger)->next;
        else {
            last = *finger;
            finger = &( (*finger)->next );
            }
        }
    theList->last = last;
    }
```

This code differs from your function in that it deletes *all* elements that match `data`, but you could modify it easily to remove the *first* element to match `data`.